# Javascript condition to use await of not

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Is there a way I can write this block of code without all the repeated code for calling axios?

```
export const handler = async (event, useAwait) => {
  const { path, data } = JSON.parse(event);

  if (useAwait) {
    return await axios(`https://example.com/api${path}`, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'api-key': key,
      },
      data: data,
    });
  } else {
    // non-blocking
    axios(`https://example.com/api${path}`, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'api-key': key,
      },
      data: data,
    });
    return true;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Put the promise into a variable, and then you can conditionally return it.

```
export const handler = async (event, useAwait) => {
    const { data } = JSON.parse(event);
    const prom = axios(`https://example.com/api${url}`, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'api-key': key,
        },
        data: data,
    });
    return useAwait ? (await prom) : true;
};
```

That said, you may as well return the Promise itself - `await`ing something that you're returning immediately doesn't help since you're not immediately inside a `try`.

```
return useAwait ? prom : true;
```

But calling this function without returning the result looks like a bad idea because then you may get an unhandled rejection. You may wish to add a `.catch` to the Promise in that case to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

```
export const handler = (event) => {
  const { path, data } = JSON.parse(event);
  const prom = axios(`https://example.com/api${path}`, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'api-key': key,
      },
      data: data,
  });
  prom.catch(()=>{}); // prevent uncaught rejection
  return prom;
}
```

If you don't test the return value of `handler` to be strictly equal to `true`, calling code can rely on promise objects being truthy in a conditional expression as needed, and the logic can be simplified to an ordinary function that returns a promise without using `await` or taking a `useAwait` parameter.

The dummy `catch` handler added to `prom` is to prevent generating an uncaught-rejected-promise error if the caller doesn't handle rejection of the axios promise, and can be omitted if uncaught rejection errors are acceptable. How calling code is meant to operate without waiting for the `axios` call completed is unclear and not covered here.

---

One of the reasons for suggesting major simplifications is the `// non-blocking` comment in the posted code. Async functions always return a promise object when called *with no blocking effect*, either to continued execution of calling code or browser operation.

The only effective difference between using `await` or not (in the post) is the value used to resolve the returned promise by `handler`.